# 406 Error When Making A Twitter Streaming API Request In Hebrew (But Not English)?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am making a Twitter API pull using Tweepy. The script works perfectly when I filter using an English word. Here is the relevant line of code:

```
twitterStream.filter(track=['banana'])
```

However, when I use a non-English word, I get a 406 error.

```
twitterStream.filter(track=['חֶבְרוֹן'])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what if you prefix it as unicode?`twitterStream.filter(track=[u'חֶבְרוֹן'])` m or maybe you will need to provide utf8 encoded string `twitterStream.filter(track=[u'חֶבְרוֹן'.encode("utf8")])`

Comment: @JoranBeasley I get an error: "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found"

Comment: oh you must be using python3 ... my bad sorry ... not sure how you can do it with python3